# How do I make a NodeJs project publicly accessible on port 3000?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, server, port

I have a NodeJs/Express project in Alibaba cloud based Ubuntu server.

When I run project and access with `curl localhost:3000` and `curl 127.0.0.1:3000` it works!

When I access with IP public, e.g. `curl 192.x.x.x:3000` it doesn't work, even though I have edited config in Express project in some code to : `server.listen(3000,"0.0.0.0") OR server.listen("3000","192.x.x.x")`.

FYI I have Apache on this server. When I access on Internet with IP public no problem. 
What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks beforehand.

PS: the `192.x.x.x` is my IP public and it works access with Apache project

Comment: Most probably the port is closed and for a good reason. You should configure a reverse proxy in apache to redirect incoming traffic on port 80 to internal port 3000. Add something like this to your virtualhost:     ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/

Comment: Are you sure, you are using public IP. and not getting confused with private IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your security ground and create a inbound rule to allow port 3000. Follow this guideline.

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25471.htm

Make sure you allow TCP traffic or all traffic from all sources to the port 3000 as the inbound rule.

Comment: thank you this works.I have set allow ingress and outbond port 3000/8000.but any risk for this?

Comment: It depends on the application that you have developed and it's vulnerabilities. If you application is secured there won't be any problem obviously.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue the following command to open port 3000 for TCP traffic.**

*sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp*

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can access your service locally  - but not publicly could mean 2 possible configurations:

1. The server running your application has blocked the port 3000
2. You have not configured your server to map the port 80 of a specific route to the port 3000

It is highly possible that a most essential part of your server configuration has not been done.

Comment: how to configure map the port 80 to route to the port 3000?

Comment: That is part of Alibaba cloud configuration, Please refer their docs for the deployment details.

Comment: Please see JKKs answer. There is a link to Alibaba help